# Redis "Client List" purpose and description

Tags: redis

While executing the "Client List" i get the below result,whats the meaning of the each flag

Slave
addr=100.0.0.0:0000 fd=5 idle=3 flags=S db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=sync

Master
addr=100.0.0.0:0000 fd=6 idle=0 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=client

Comment: You can use the Redis official documentation to understand these flags as well: https://redis.io/commands/client-list/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With client list, Redis prints one row per connected client.
From the redis.h and networking.c files of Redis source code:

- addr: address/port of the client
- fd: file descriptor corresponding to the socket
- idle: idle time of the connection in seconds
- flags: client flags (see below)
- db: current database ID
- sub: number of channel subscriptions
- psub: number of pattern matching subscriptions
- qbuf: query buffer length (0 means no query pending)
- obl: output buffer length
- oll: output list length (replies are queued in this list when the buffer is full)
- events: file descriptor events (see below)
- cmd: last command played

The client flags can be a combination of:

- O: the client is a slave in MONITOR mode
- S: the client is a normal slave server
- M: the client is a master
- x: the client is in a MULTI/EXEC context
- b: the client is waiting in a blocking operation
- i: the client is waiting for a VM I/O
- d: a watched keys has been modified - EXEC will fail
- c: connection to be closed after writing entire reply
- u: the client is unblocked
- N: no specific flag set

The file descriptor events can be:

- r: the client socket is readable (event loop)
- w: the client socket is writable (event loop)

It is my interpretation, please take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: The description still confuses me a little. e.g. what is the difference between
"obl: output buffer length"
vs
omem: output buffer memory usage".

Also, what is the unit for all "length" fields ?

Comment: This description is 5 years old, and predates the "client list" entry in the Redis documentation (which is more up-to-date, and the one you should use). Lengths are expressed in bytes. obl is the size of the output communication buffer. omem is the estimated size of the reply. obl != omem for multiple reasons.

Comment: According to code comments: omem is the number of bytes that Redis is virtually using to store the reply still not read by the client. It is "virtual" since the reply output list may contain objects that are shared and are not really using additional memory. It represents the total sum of the length of all the objects stored in the output list, plus the memory used to allocate every list node.