# is there a way to get the client IP in redis?

Tags: redis

I did a web search but found nothing on this. I am running redis on a cluster and would like to find out which machine is connecting to redis ( especially when no machine is supposed to be connecting, but redis still says some machine connected).

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With MONITOR, only the clients actually sending traffic to Redis will be shown. If you just need to get a list of connected clients, you can use the CLIENT LIST command.

```
$ redis-cli client list
```

It will return a table whose fields are described there:

[Redis "Client List" purpose and description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9288570/redis-client-list-purpose-and-description/9332729#9332729)

Answer (score 6):

Did you try the MONITOR command?

http://redis.io/commands/monitor

```
 $ redis-cli monitor
 1339518083.107412 [0 127.0.0.1:60866] "keys" "*"
 1339518087.877697 [0 127.0.0.1:60866] "dbsize"
 1339518090.420270 [0 127.0.0.1:60866] "set" "x" "6"
 1339518096.506257 [0 127.0.0.1:60866] "get" "x"
 1339518099.363765 [0 127.0.0.1:60866] "del" "x"
 1339518100.544926 [0 127.0.0.1:60866] "get" "x"
 Use SIGINT (Ctrl-C) to stop a MONITOR stream running via redis-cli.

 # OR 
 $ telnet localhost 6379
 Trying 127.0.0.1...
 Connected to localhost.
 Escape character is '^]'.
 MONITOR
 +OK
 +1339518083.107412 [0 127.0.0.1:60866] "keys" "*"
 +1339518087.877697 [0 127.0.0.1:60866] "dbsize"
 +1339518090.420270 [0 127.0.0.1:60866] "set" "x" "6"
 +1339518096.506257 [0 127.0.0.1:60866] "get" "x"
 +1339518099.363765 [0 127.0.0.1:60866] "del" "x"
 +1339518100.544926 [0 127.0.0.1:60866] "get" "x"
 QUIT
 +OK
 Connection closed by foreign host.
```