# Cannot run CLIENT command at GCP managed Redis

Tags: google-cloud-platform, redis

I created a Redis at GCP. Note it is GCP service, not a Redis created using compute engine. But when I run redis-cli and then run CLIENT command, like "client list", "client kill", etc. it showed:

`(error) ERR unknown command 'client', with args beginning with:`

Look like it does not support command about CLIENT, and maybe some other commands as well.
 
If I run "info" in the redis-cli, it shows the version is: `redis_version:4.0.14`

How to have the GCP managed Redis run command of "client"? I need to disconnect with all  clients so I want to run "client kill".

if "client kill" is not available, can I use "shutdown" as a workaround? I am not sure if shutdown will terminate the redis or just stop it. if it just stops the redis and no data is lost, then I can use it as well.

Comment: Can you share the documentation consulted when using GCP managed redis? Did you use GCP documentation or Redis guides?

Comment: I use https://redis.io/commands/client-kill. GCP redis blocked all CLIENT  commands and SHUTDOWN command.

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is with CLIENT LIST command which currently is not available in Memorystore for Redis. Memorystore for Redis is a managed service and comes with some constraints. So some commands that interfere with a managed Redis service are blocked as per [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/product-constraints#blocked_redis_commands).

As a workaround you can use the MONITOR command which is available for instances created after November 4, 2019. From the [Redis documentation](https://redis.io/commands/monitor) the MONITOR is a debugging command that streams back every command processed by the Redis server.

MONITOR will show the clients sending traffic to Redis server, as mentioned in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11668990/11866104).

There is a [PIT](https://issuetracker.google.com/169419385) for this issue as Feature request. Please feel free to post there if you have further concern on that issue.

Comment: Thanks Mahboob. Is there any other way to disconnect all clients of redis if CLIENT KILL and SHUTDOWN are not available?

Comment: @user389955, I will look for this to get back to you